# Borsuk--Ulam question

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

A version of the Borsuk--Ulam theorem states that a continuous antipodal map from the M-sphere into euclidean N-space has a zero
provided that M is at least N. Clearly the general case follows from the case when M = N. But is the case when M >> N any easier to prove than the equidimensional case?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a direct and easier proof when $M >> N$?

Comment: (Hi Tony!) Please explain: why do you expect the proof to be easier when M>>N? 

Comment: Dear Somnath, Yes, that's what I was asking. 

Hi Piero, I'm not sure that I do "expect" it to be easier -- but as the nonequidimensional case is a "trivial" consequence of the equidimensional case, I wondered if perhaps there was a shorter route to it. It seems not by the answer below.

Comment: It's a shame about that answer, as the question was a very nice one. I suppose there's still just about room for the optimist to wonder whether there is a short proof of the Borsuk--Ulam theorem that starts by proving it in very high dimensions.

Comment: Hi Tony! Could you specify what you mean by "easier", ie are you looking for a proof that doesn't appeal to the fact that an antipode-preserving map $f\colon S^n\to S^n$ is of odd degree, therefore homotopically non-trivial?

Comment: Tim, there is a relatively short argument via dimensional 
reduction which is a hybrid of one of Shchepin's together with
a low-dimensional argument reminiscent of the Stokes' theorem 
proof of the Brouwer fixed point theorem. See  http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~carbery/analysis/links.html 
and click on Notes on the Borsuk--Ulam theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so, since any antipodal (non-existent) map $S^n\to S^{n-1}$ would easily be "suspended" to an antipodal map $S^{n+1}\to S^n$. Iterating and composing would then yield antipodal maps $S^m\to S^{n-1}$ with arbitrarily large $m$. The $n=2$ case is somewhat easier though.

Comment: ..and the case $n=1$ and is even easier.